# How to clean up a UIViewController in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Consider we have a custom UIViewContoller.

Now we have to make some clean up on UIViewController unload. For example, if we use UIWebView as a subview in our view controller, it's recommended to set its delegate to `null` and call `StopLoading()` method on unload.

Some sources say it's not recommended to make clean up overriding `Dispose()` method, because it concerns only managed object lifecycle.

Other sources say it's not recommended to use `ViewDidDissappear()` for these purposes because it can be called twice.

How to handle it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ViewDidDisappear()` and `ViewWillDisappear()` will not be called multiple times; at least not without a balanced call to `ViewDidAppear()` and `ViewWillAppear()`. If you see more calls to the *disappear* methods than to the *appear* methods, you have a bug in your code. If you want to make sure, your cleanup happens only once (for sanity), but isn't the solution something as simple as this:

```
bool myCleanupIsDone = false;

public override void ViewDidDisappear()
{
  if(myCleanupIsDone)
  {
    return;
  }

  myCleanupIsDone = true;
  CleanUpWhateverNeedsToBeCleanedUp();
}
```

You should almost [never need to override](http://blog.pluralsight.com/idisposable-for-dummies-1-why-what) `Dispose()` unless you are dealing with unmanaged resources. Xamarin.iOS does that a lot internally but for your code and in your case it is not relevant.

Normally you would create your required objects in `ViewWillAppear()` and clean them up in the disappear methods. That way you would not need to check if something has already been cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewWillDisappear` and `ViewDidDisappear` can actually be called multiple times, on iPhone for example every time when a new controller is presented or pushed. But I think it's still the right place to do all the necessary cleanups.

Krumelur's proposal would end in a null delegate of your `UIWebView` once your controller has been disappeared for the first time – if the user comes back, it would probably crash.

So instead of setting a flag you could check, if the controller you want to clean up is beeing popped or dismissed – if that's the case, you can safely do all the work.

Here's some code I found in one of my projects (seems I've been through this before ;)):

```
public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
{
          if ((NavigationController == null && IsMovingFromParentViewController) ||
              (ParentViewController != null && ParentViewController.IsBeingDismissed))
          {
              CleanUpAfterDisappearing();
          }

          base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);
}
```

Comment: What and when to call depends _what_ the intention is. If something gets initialized when the controller appears, it makes perfect sense to clean up every time.

Comment: Sure, but your sample proposes to load/initialize only once, so it would not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just cleanup resources when the operating system instructs your app to do so via overriding the DidReceiveMemoryWarning() method in your custom view controllers: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.DidReceiveMemoryWarning